# Shorten the often used line Theme.of(context).colorScheme

Tags: flutter

Everytime I need to access the colors of my current Theme in Flutter, I have to write `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.{come color}`.
This means I have to write this in almost every line I need to use a color and is a HUGE hassle.

It would perhaps be shorter if I made a variable in every class' I needed the colors `build()` method, like: `final colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme`.
But that still means I have to write this in every class.

Is there a way to make an abbreviation of this that I can import from a file and use in the whole file in all classes without writing the same thing over and over again?

**ANSWER:**

I found this GitHub repo with the perfect solution for everyone, that was also stated by @Md. Yeasin Sheikh's answer.
[The GitHub repo file with the solution and more convenient shortcuts for most used lines of code:](https://github.com/IsaiasCuvula/flutter_riverpod_todo_app/blob/main/lib/utils/extensions.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension BuildContextExtensions on BuildContext {
    ThemeData get _theme => Theme.of(this);
    TextTheme get textTheme => _theme.textTheme;
    ColorScheme get colorScheme => _theme.colorScheme;
    Size get deviceSize => MediaQuery.sizeOf(this);
}
```

**Then, to access the current color scheme:** Import the file with this defined extension, and **where you want to access the theme, use:** `context.colorScheme`.

Usage example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: context.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
        child: Text(
            'Example container',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: context.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create extension on `BuildContext` like,

```dart
extension MyThemeExtension on BuildContext {
  ColorScheme get colorSchema => Theme.of(this).colorScheme;
}
```

Then use like `context.colorSchema;` But actually I prefer writing full line of code like

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final theme = Theme.of(context);
  final colorSchema = theme.colorSchema;
  final textTheme = theme.textTheme;

  return Scaffold(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a utility folder and add this code snippet.

`getColorScheme(context) => Theme.of(context).colorScheme;`

Now use it wherever you want as :

```
Container(
   'My text',
   color: getColorScheme(context).primary,
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own getter for that

```
get appColors(BuildContext context)=>Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
```

And you can call it like

```
Container(
   'Example of shorten colorScheme',
   color: appColors(context).onBackground,
  )
```

Voila !